# Row visibility expression using ReportItem collection not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

This is major edit from the previous version of this question, which would hold little of value for future readers anyway.

I have a report where I want to hide certain rows depending on the data in certain fields, but also be able to override this based on a parameter value.

So for my visibility (Hidden), I am using the following expression:

```
=iif(CDbl(ReportItems!tbOEM1.Value) >= 20 Or CDbl(ReportItems!tbOEM2.Value) >= 20 Or CDbl(ReportItems!tbOEM3.Value) >= 20 Or Parameters!OEM20.Value.Equals(False)
,    False
,   True
)
```

Which I think should mean, if any of the 3 `tbOEM` fields are >= 20, then display the row.  But if the user has selected **False** for the "OEM20" parameter (Boolean), display all the rows regardless of the values.

However, when I run the report and choose **True** for the OEM20 parameter, No rows get displayed, even though I know that there are rows that have OEM values over 20.

To investigate, I added a background color expression to each of the tbOEM reportitems.  Here is the background color expression for tbOEM1:

```
=iif(CDbl(ReportItems!tbOEM1.Value) >= 20
,   "Red"
,   "White"
)
```

When I run the report with False for the OEM20 parameter, I see all rows returned, and no fields are colored Red, even the ones that should be because they are tbOEM fields with a value >=20.

So I wonder if this is an order of execution issue where the value of the ReportItem is not yet known when setting visibility and background color?  Is this known and documented anywhere?  I googled and couldn't find anything.

Or am I doing something else wrong that is fixable?

**I already know that a workaround is to use the datafield calculations that populate the tbOEM fields in the expressions, rather than the ReportItems collection.  So you needn't bother to tell me about this option.**

Comment: Is the OEM20 parameter multi-value? Might need something like `Array.IndexOf(Parameters!OEM20.Value, 0) > -1` or use InStr with JOIN.

Comment: What type is `OEM20`? In your code you treat it as an integer `0` but in your question you say the user selects a string `"0"`. You should probably have either string comparison `Parameters!OEM20.Value.Equals("0")` or integer comparison `Parameters!OEM20.Value = 0`

Comment: Your comments led me closer to a solution, and I have edited the question accordingly.  Sorry the comments prior to this won't make sense in the context of the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some things to try. Putting this as an answer as it will be too big for a comment.

I'm still thinking something weird is happening with type comparison/conversion.

Maybe the `tbOEM` textboxes are strings with non-numeric characters (even just a space) so the `CDbl` conversion is failing, and thus failing the `CDbl(ReportItems!tbOEM1.Value) >= 20` test even though it looks like it is above 20 when displayed as a string. Given your background colour expression is also failing, this seems to be the case. Let's use the `Val` expression for the comparison instead:

```
Val(ReportItems!tbOEM1.Value) >= 20
```

`Val` doesn't give errors when converting to a numeric value, it just does the best it can and returns whatever number it finds. Convert the field into the numeric value for display purposes as well as for the background colour expression so we see what the expression sees, not just the displayed text. On your `tbOEM1` textbox use these expressions for the following properties:

**Value**

```
=Val(Fields!OEM1.Value)
```

**Background.Color**

```
=iif(Val(ReportItems!tbOEM1.Value) >= 20, "Red", "White")
```

If this still fails (for example, the textbox no longer displays a value) then let's trim it first to get rid of any spaces: `=Val(Trim(Fields!OEM1.Value))`

If the `OEM1` field is a decimal value use `20.0` rather than `20` so it is comparing to a Double rather than an Integer in case something funky is happening with the implicit type conversion in the comparison.

Okay, now hopefully the textboxes are displaying the correct number and the background is being coloured correctly. Now we just need to fix the `Visibility.Hidden` expression for the row. I wouldn't use `Value.Equals` here as the parameter is already a boolean so we can just use it directly:

```
=iif(Val(ReportItems!tbOEM1.Value) >= 20 Or Val(ReportItems!tbOEM2.Value) >= 20 Or Val(ReportItems!tbOEM3.Value) >= 20 Or Not Parameters!OEM20.Value
    , False
    , True
)
```

This needs to be applied to the entire row by selecting the handle for the row on the left of the tablix, rather than applied to the textboxes directly.

Of course, add the `Trim` function if the experiment above required it.

Good luck! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Chris, although this wasn't the answer, while I was trying the things you suggested, I found my mistake and corrected it.  Have an upvote, but I'm debating deleting the question, as I'm not sure the answer contains any useful wisdom for future readers.  ; )

Comment: @TabAlleman If the question and answer have no value for future visitors, go ahead and delete it. This wasn't so much an answer as a bunch of experiments to try but was too big for a comment. I'm glad you got it resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your generous help, I'll delete the question in the next 24 hours.

Comment: @TabAlleman All good